# Can a type of variable be an object in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

I hope my question is clear. I would like to do something like this:

```
TYPE tipo = int;
tipo = float;
```

To later be able to do other things like these:

```
void* ptr = new tipo();
cout << *(tipo*)ptr;
```

It's, basically, to determinate the type of a void-pointer (or a `variant`-object, or a `any`-object) and its de-reference, but in execution time.

This is my whole problem: I'm trying to create an array of any type of variable (simulating the RAM of a PC for a compiler). For this I'm using void pointers and other array where I store an integer which represents the type of the element was stored in the first array. So then I can cast properly the element when it's required. This code works, but of course it's no so functional because I would have to use all the switch-case each time I have to recover an element from my array:

```
#define INT     0
#define FLOAT   1
#define BOOL    2

int main(void)
{
    void* ram[] = { new float(2.5), new float(5.8), new bool(true), new int(8) };
    int tipo[]  = { FLOAT,          FLOAT,          BOOL,           INT       };

    int i = 1;
    int salida;

    switch (i)
    {
        case INT:   salida = *(int*)ram[i];     break;
        case FLOAT: salida = *(float*)ram[i];   break;
        case BOOL:  salida = *(bool*)ram[i];    break;
    }

    cout << salida;

    return 86;
}
```

I wonder if I coudl have an "array of types", so I coudl do something like this

```
int main(void)
{
    void* ram[] = { new float(2.5), new float(5.8), new bool(true), new int(8) };
    TYPE tipo[] = { float,          float,          bool,           int       };

    int i = 1;
    int salida = *(tipo[i]*)ram[i];

    cout << salida;

    return 86;
}
```

Is it possible? If no, how would you solve this problem?

Comment: Unrelated: consider replacing the `#defines` with an `enum`.

Comment: Note: because `salida` is an `int`, what you're trying to do is of limited use. You might as well simply store `int`s because you've lost the `float` or `bool`-ness ass soon as you make the assignment to `salida`.

Comment: If you have some common operations that you need all types to support (e.g., printable) and want to make doing those operations easier, you can use something like [dyno](https://github.com/ldionne/dyno). When it comes to type erasure, there are numerous options fitting different situations. Giving a lot of detail on the requirements of your code will help in picking the best one.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks. I'm trying to do a compiler and simulate its perform running the programs that It compile, so "ram" is the memory where the programmer can store anything, but storing its type of variable also. Casting them like an "int" is just an example.

Comment: I think the question is if there's a standard way to make it so types can be inferred at run-time like in interpreted languages.

Answer (score 4):

Your first block of code is basically OK but not good for performance because there is overhead associated with every `new` allocation, and you're paying that price for every single element of data.

Your second block of code is not really viable, at least not in the way you propose.

There is a better solution: a vector of variants.  In your case:

```
std::vector<std::variant<int, float, bool>> values;
```

You can store all three types in here, like this:

```
values.emplace_back(2.5f);
values.emplace_back(5.8f);
values.emplace_back(true);
values.emplace_back(8);
```

This container is resizable, holds all your data in a single large allocation (which for small types greatly reduces allocation overhead), and can be expanded to support more types with no extra work.

Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: It's worth noting that std::variant is a relatively new feature in C++; it might not be supported by all compilers...

Comment: @paulsm4 std::variant is in C++17 and is supported by every current major C++ compiler, but fair enough, OP might be using an old compiler, in which case `boost::variant` can be used, or any number of variant libraries.

Comment: The question does say "any type of variable", which I take to mean the list of types is open, but then the code in the question maps types to integers, which requires a closed list. Based on that, I'm not sure if `variant` is appropriate or not.

Comment: @chris: I don't think the set of types is unbounded, but if it is, `std::any` can be used instead of `std::variant`.

Comment: It seems to solve my problem. Let me learn about "variant" and I will comnent you. Thanks a lot @John Zwinck!

Comment: @AliRojas: You're welcome.  If this answer or any of the other answers to questions you've posted solved your problems, please do "accept" them by clicking the checkmark on the left.  I noticed you have quite a few prior questions for which you didn't accept any answer.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: vector is a lot more suitable for my case, thanks!. About `variant`, according to I have understood of my readings, to properly de-reference it, I have to necessarily specify the type of the element stored, for example for: `variant<int, float> x = 1.8f`, I have to use: `get<float>(x)` to recover properly the datum stored. Is that right? If it is, so I would have to use my horrible switch-case again and that's just what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I would like to determinate the type of the de-referenced datum during the execution time.

Comment: What does "determine" mean?  You want to print out the name of the type?  Or you want to act on the datum?  If you want to act on the datum, in C++ you have to write code which knows at compile time how to act on it.  There's no such thing in C++ as "I don't care what the type is, let's just print the value!" for example.

Answer (score 2):

While John's answer is definitely a good suggestion about how you should approach your problem, to strictly answer your title question, there is a [std::type_info](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) class which stores type information. It allows e.g. to compare types or print their names.

You can use [typeid()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) to retrieve it:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const std::type_info& info = typeid(float);
  std::cout << info.name() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but you can't declare a variable of type taken from a `type_info`.

Comment: Oh yes, sure. This is mostly for the people who might come here being redirected by a search engine.