# C++ Universal Variable easy to create and de-reference

Tags: c++, variant

For some time, I have been trying to build this chimera or something that works like that: a class that can store different types of variable, and which could be created and de-referenced easily, without having to write de type stored each time that it's used. E.g. to be able to do something like this:

```
DATO d;

d = "Puedo almacenar lo que sea";
string s = d;

d = 3.1416;
float f = d;

d = true;
bool b = d;
```

I need it to create an "Universal Compiler" (yeah, another chimera). I think that I have nearly been able to reach my target, let me show how:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
using namespace std;

class DATO
{
    variant<int,float,char,bool,string> v;

    public:
    DATO() {}
    DATO(int    i)  { v = i; }
    DATO(float  f)  { v = f; }
    DATO(char   c)  { v = c; }
    DATO(bool   b)  { v = b; }
    DATO(string s)  { v = s; }

    DATO(double d)  { v = float(d); }
    DATO(char c[])  { string s = c; v = s; }

    operator int()    const { return *(get_if<int>   (&v)); }
    operator float()  const { return *(get_if<float> (&v)); }
    operator char()   const { return *(get_if<char>  (&v)); }
    operator bool()   const { return *(get_if<bool>  (&v)); }
    operator string() const { return *(get_if<string>(&v)); }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, DATO const &);

};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, DATO const &d)
{
    switch (d.v.index())
    {
        case 0:  return os << get<int>   (d.v);
        case 1:  return os << get<float> (d.v);
        case 2:  return os << get<char>  (d.v);
        case 3:  return os << get<bool>  (d.v);
        case 4:  return os << get<string>(d.v);
        default: return os << "";
    }
}
```

Of course it's just an example, and `DATO` just serves to store and print some types of data, no to operate them (but I think that overloading operators and functions properly, it could expand its uses). Now let's see how `DATO` works:

```
#define SL cout<<endl

int main(void)
{
    DATO d;

    d = 9;
    int i=d;
    d = i-2*i;
    cout << i; SL;
    cout << d; SL;SL;

    d = 1.618034;
    float f = d;
    d = 1/f;
    cout << f; SL;
    cout << d; SL;SL;

    d = 'a';
    char c = d;
    d = char(int(c) - 32);
    cout << c; SL;
    cout << d; SL;SL;

    d = true;
    bool b = d;
    d = b && false;
    cout << b; SL;
    cout << d; SL;SL;

    d = "Hola desbordadores de pila";
    string s = d;
    s = s + ".";
    cout << d; SL;
    cout << s; SL;SL;

    SL;SL;

    return 86;
}
```

The out put is just how you imagine:

```
9
-9

1.61803
0.618034

a
A

1
0

Hola desbordadores de pila
Hola desbordadores de pila.
```

How you can see, type DATO can store many different types of data and it can be easily de-referenced just taking care of treat the getted data properly. It nearly works just like I wanted, but I don't know if I'm falling in a bad practice doing it. Please, tell me if you see any problem in my implementation. Until now, I have seen just a problem, when I store a `string` in it, and try to copy it into a normal `string` variable previously declared, e.g.:

```
    d = "Hola desbordadores de pila";
    string s
    s = d;
```

I get this error: "ambiguous overload for 'operator='". Until now, it just happens with `string`s and I don't know why. I will be gratefull for any comment about this error or any other problem that you could see in my implementation.

PD: Yeah, I have learned some facts about the limits of the C++ language (e.g. its statically typed feature) in this wonderfull comunity. You can see some of my steps here: [Can a type of variable be an object in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212707/can-a-type-of-variable-be-an-object-in-c), [C++: Is it posible to set the type of a void-pointer, variant-object or any-object in execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63221276/c-is-it-posible-to-set-the-type-of-a-void-pointer-variant-object-or-any-obje)

Comment: `get_if()` returns `nullptr` if the requested type has not been stored in the `variant`. So, for example, if you store an `int` and then any operator other than `operator int()` is called, `*(get_if<...>(&v))` will cause **undefined behavior** due to dereferencing `nullptr`. Your getters should use `std::get` instead, so that a `std::bad_variant_access` exception will be thrown on a mismatch, which is well-defined behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Remy Lebeau, I must to think a trick to avoid or manage that situation.

Comment: As for the "ambiguous overload" error, `std::string` has overloaded `operator=` that accept both `string` and `char` as input, and your `DATO` can implicitly convert to both of those types, so the compiler doesn't know which conversion to perform. So you need to be explicit about which conversion you want to perform, eg: `s = static_cast<string>(d);`

Comment: Instead of manual dispatch, you might use `std::visit`: `return std::visit([&](const auto& v){ os << v; }, d.v);`

Comment: [unconstexpr](https://github.com/DaemonSnake/unconstexpr#compile-time-type-safe-any-value-not-constexpr) might interest you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There is any way to avoid that ambiguity modifying the code inside the class? To don't have to write `static_cast<string>` each time that I need to recover the string stored.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42, I have never used `visit` before, is it an special function for evaluate all possible types of a `variant`? When I try your suggest I get this `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'ostream&' from an rvalue of type 'void'`

Comment: @AliRojas "*There is any way to avoid that ambiguity modifying the code inside the class?*" - you could expose a non-operator method in `DATO`, such as `string asString() const`, and then you can call it like `s = d.asString();`

Comment: @AliRojas "*is [visit] an special function for evaluate all possible types of a variant*" - read [this `std::visit` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). "*When I try your suggest I get this error*" - then you are not using it correctly.  Please show your actual code.

Comment: I miss the return in the lambda :/ `return std::visit([&](const auto& v){ return os << v; }, d.v);`.